# White list of HTML tags I should allow from user generated content?

Tags: php, security

All,

I am building a small site using PHP.  In the site, I receive user-generated text content.  I want to allow some safe HTML tag (e.g., formatting) as well as MathML.  How do I go about compiling a white list for a `strip_tags()` function?  Is there a well accepted white list I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard `strip_tags` function is not enough for security, since it doesn't validate attributes at all. Use a more complete library explicitly for the purpose of completely sanitizing HTML like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Comment: Another good resource is the [OWASP XSS prevention cheatsheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to not allow javascript through, then your whitelist of tags is going to be pretty close to the empty set.
Remember that pretty much all tags can have [event attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp) that contain javascript code to be executed when the specified event occurs.

If you don't want to go down the HTMLPurifier kind of route, consider a different language, such as [markdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/) (that this site uses) or some other wiki-like markup language; however, be sure to disable any use of passthrough HTML that may be allowed.